# Error checks with user input

Tags: javascript, for-loop, error-handling

I'm having trouble with getting error checking to work by validating user input.  It worked fine up until I tried adding the error checking, because the range is supposed to be 1-10. I know that I could set the input box in HTML to that range, but for this assignment, we're supposed to use an error message if it's out of that range. I'm just looking for help to understand where I went wrong here. Thanks!

Here is my coding:

```js
function OddNumber() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
  try {
    if (x < 1 || x > 10)
  } //less than 1 or greater than 10 creates an error (in theory)
  catch (err) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = err.name;
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) { //gets input from user and loops to find odd numbers between 1 and that number
      if (i % 2 != 0) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (i + " ");
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1>Odd Number Generator</h1>

<p>Enter a number between 1 and 10, then click "Submit" to get the odd numbers between 1 and the number you entered.</p>

<p>Number: <input type="number" id="input" name="input"></p>
<p><button onclick="OddNumber()">Submit</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: The browser will be complaining about a syntax error in the console.

Comment: You do not need `try/catch` to check for a number range. The brackets are completely off: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zyf1049r/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with:

```
if(x < 1 || x > 10) } //less than 1 or greater than 10 creates an error (in theory)
    catch(err) {
```

The `if` statement has nothing after it which would be easier to see if the brackets were alligned properly. And you don't need try/catch for this kind of error checking.

```
<script>
function OddNumber () {
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
    if(x < 1 || x > 10) { //less than 1 or greater than 10 creates an error (in theory)
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your error string";
    } else {
        for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) { //gets input from user and loops to find odd numbers between 1 and that number
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're right, err.name was from the try/catch block I removed. You should put your own error string there.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking `if(x < 1 || x > 10)` doesn't throw an error. You would need to `throw new Error()` in the if, if you need to use the catch block for your assignment. Though it's not really needed at all.

Also I think you mean to be using the `+=` operator on the innerHTML.

```js
function OddNumber () {
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
    if(x < 1 || x > 10){
          
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "invalid number";  
    } //less than 1 or greater than 10 report error
    else {
        for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) { //gets input from user and loops to find odd numbers between 1 and that number
          if (i % 2 != 0) {
           document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += (i + " ");
          }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Odd Number Generator</title>
<meta Charset="utf-8">
</head>
<h1>Odd Number Generator</h1>

<body>



<p>Enter a number between 1 and 10, then click  "Submit" to get the odd numbers between 1 and the number you entered.</p>


  <p>Number: <input type="number" id="input" name="input"></p>
  <p><button onclick="OddNumber()">Submit</button>
  <p id="output"></p>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I did mean to use the += operator. I'll try using the throw new error, but the odd number function is working again like it did before whatever I did with the error message coding.